# Response JSON object or JSON.stringify?

Tags: json, node.js, express

Suppose I want to return JSON content

```
var content = {
  a: 'foo',
  b: 'bar'
};
```

What is the best practice to return my JSON data?

A) Return object as is; i.e `res.end(content)`?

B) `JSON.stringify(content)` and then call `JSON.parse(content)` on the client?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you send the response with express's `res.json` you can send the Object directly as `application/json` encoded response.

```
app.get('/route/to/ressource', function(req, res){
  var oMyOBject = {any:'data'};

   res.json(oMyOBject);
});
```

Comment: Yes I am aware of that functionality. However I just wanted to know what are the pros and cons? Why would one prefer to convert into string or the other way round?

Comment: @dopplesoldner In fact, `res.send()` has already done the stringify works, whatever you did, client will always receives the JSON formatted data.

Comment: You don't need to set the type because `.send` will do it for you, and you can do `app.set('json spaces', '\t')` if you want formatted output.

Answer (score 8):

The client must always send a string. That's what the protocol says. After all, HTTP is a wide-ranging protocol, and not all languages support JSON objects, let alone JavaScript data.

If you don't convert it to a JSON string, chances are that pure Node will just send it as `[object Object]`, and i'm sure that's not your intention.

As mentioned previously, Express lets you send an actual JS object, and does the JSON string converting for you. Alternately, you can manually convert it.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the protocol is to always send a string instead of an object? And `res.json()` does the conversion internally?

Also if I am sending a string from the server, I will require `JSON.parse(data)` on the browser?

Comment: Yes. If you use jQuery's `$.getJSON()` method, it does the `JSON.parse()` internally also.