# Dynamically change JSON spacing with Express.js

Tags: json, node.js, express

I know you can configure Express to output either pretty JSON (`app.set("json spaces", 2)`) or minified JSON (`app.set("json spaces", 0)`), but is there a way to override this global setting on a particular response?

For example, if I set `json spaces` to `0`, I could pretty print doing something like:

```
app.get("/foo", function(req,res) {
   res.json({"a":"b"}, 2);
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stringify wasn't working for me, for whatever reason. But setting `json spaces` did work.

```
app.set('json spaces', 2);

app.get("*", async (request, response) => {
  ...
  response.json(m);
}
```

http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.set

Thank you to [loganfsmyth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22580998/response-json-object-or-json-stringify#comment34377088_22581168) for the tip.

Comment: You don't need `.type('application/json')` if you're using `.json()`.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks, @EtienneMartin.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do it would be to use res.send and format the JSON on your own:

```
app.get("/foo", function(req,res) {
   res.send(JSON.stringify({"a":"b"}, null, 2));
});
```

MDN has more documentation on [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the great answer [wjohnsto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3272249/wjohnsto)! Building off of your answer, and digging around in [the response.js code](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L232), I had to make one modification to get it to work properly:

```
app.get("/foo", function(req, res) {
   res
     .set("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
     .send(JSON.stringify({"a":"b"}, null, 2));
});
```

I ended up creating a function `sendPretty(res, data)` for reusability.