# Node.js express - Setting header to json format not working

Tags: json, node.js, express

I have created a little API using node.js, express and mysql. It's returning the json as expected. Now I would like to set the header `.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')` too.

How do I need to alter this part to do so?

Working:

```
...
module.exports = app;
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(4001);
```

Attempts (Not working):

```
...
module.exports = app;
//var server = http.createServer(app);
var server = http.createServer(function(req,res){
      res.statusCode = 200;
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.send(app);
      res.end();
});
server.listen(4001);
```

Found my mistake. Had to use:

```
res.json({"status": 200, "error": error, "response": null});
```

instead of

```
res.send(JSON.stringify({"status": 200, "error": null, "response": results}));
```

Comment: try res.json({app});

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work. Getting 'TypeError: res.json is not a function' and nodemon says 'app crashed'

Comment: wait, you are not using express?

Comment: Yes, I am using express ...

Comment: looks like you are doing using only HTTP module. app is your express object ?

Comment: Yes ... defined var app = express(); at the top

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165511/discussion-between-rahul-sharma-and-philipp-m).

Comment: Could it be res.json(app); Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22580998/response-json-object-or-json-stringify